# Form field value instead of it's index

Tags: symfony

Here is my FormBuilder:

```
         // EditUserFormType.php
         $builder
                ->add('eduStartYear', 'choice', array(
                    'label' => false,
                    'choices' => range(date('Y'),1956)
                ))
                ->add('eduEndYear', 'choice', array(
                    'label' => false,
                    'choices' => range(date('Y'),1957),
                ))
                ->add('save', 'submit');
```

And this is from Entity:

```
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $eduStartYear;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $eduEndYear;
```

This is part of controller:

```
    $user = $this->getUser();
    $form = $this->createForm(new EditUserFormType(), $user);

    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();
    }
```

I get this error on save:

> FatalErrorException in DateType.php line 53:
>
> Error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object

After I went through all process with debugger I noticed that the value passed to

`public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)`

is actually integer, and this integer is the index of form value (eg 0 = 2015, 1 = 2014 etc.)

How do I get value from form field instead of it's index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not create a choice list as per the docs where array key == value.

E.g.

```
$builder->add('eduStartYear', 'choice', array(
    'choices' => array(
        '1990'   => '1990',
        '1991'   => '1991',
        '1992'   => '1992', // of course you have to generate this array - just an example
    ),
));
```

Doctrine will still expect a DateTime object for your date field though which will cause the error with ->format. You cound look into a [data transformer](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html) to convert from your YYYY value into a DateTime object and back.

I have not syntax checked this but it should work or be close to working.

```
class YearToDateTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    private $manager;

    public function __construct(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $this->manager = $manager;
    }

    /**
     * Transforms an object (\DateTime) to a string (year).
     *
     * @param  \DateTime|null $date
     * @return string
     */
    public function transform($date)
    {
        if (null === $date) {
            return '';
        }

        return $date->format('Y');
    }

    /**
     * Transforms a year to a \DateTime
     *
     * @param  string $year
     * @return \DateTime|null
     * @throws TransformationFailedException if object (\DateTime) is not found.
     */
    public function reverseTransform($year)
    {
        if (!$year) {

            return;
        }

        $date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y', $year);

        if (!$date instanceof \DateTime) {
            throw new TransformationFailedException(sprintf(
                'Coul not convert year %s to \DateTime',
                $year
            ));
        }

        return $date;
    }
}
```

Then you can attach it to your form field like so:

```
  $builder->get('eduStartYear')
            ->addModelTransformer(new YearToDateTransformer());
```